# Why does my IDFT Computation differ from the value np.fft.ifft?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to validate a simple IDFT routine I wrote -

```
###############################################################
#My IDFT Routines
###############################################################
def simple_idft(data_f):
    data_t_r = []
    data_t_i = []
    for ii in range(0,len(data_f)):
      tmp_r=0.00
      tmp_i=0.00
      scale = 1.00/len(data_f)
      for jj in range(0,len(data_f)):
        tmp_r += data_f[jj].real*math.cos(2.00*math.pi*ii*jj/len(data_f)) - data_f[jj].imag*math.sin(2.00*math.pi*ii*jj/len(data_f))
        tmp_i += data_f[jj].real*math.sin(2.00*math.pi*ii*jj/len(data_f)) + data_f[jj].imag*math.cos(2.00*math.pi*ii*jj/len(data_f))
      tmp_r *=scale
      tmp_i *=scale
      data_t_r.append(tmp_r)
      data_t_i.append(tmp_i)
   return data_t_r, data_t_i
    

def rms_idft(data_t_r, data_t_i):
    rms = []
    for ii in range(0,len(data_t_r)):
        rms.append(math.sqrt(data_t_r[ii]**2 + data_t_i[ii]**2))
    return rms

def do_idft(data_t):
    data_t_r, data_t_i = simple_idft(data_t)
    rms = rms_idft(data_t_r, data_t_i)
    return(rms)
```

against the numpy IDFT routine -

```
################################################################
#Transform OFDM Data to time domain
################################################################
def IDFT(OFDM_data):
    return np.fft.ifft(OFDM_data)
```

I seem to get very different results when I run these (64 point data) -

```
OFDM_time = IDFT(OFDM_data)
print ("Number of OFDM samples in time-domain before CP: ", len(OFDM_time))
print(OFDM_time)
plt.plot(OFDM_time)
plt.show()
```

[image: NUMPY]

```
rms = []
rms = do_idft(OFDM_data)
plt.plot(rms,label='raj')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Can you see any error in my algorithm ?

Comment: You are applying the scale during every iteration of the inner loop.  It needs to be OUTSIDE that loop.  Also, you shouldn't be using globals.  Just have the function create and return the two lists.

Comment: Thanks you Tim, I corrected the scaling and re-casted the code as you suggested. I still get different results

Comment: Your inner loop equations are wrong. You need to implement the multiplication of two complex numbers. You're not doing that and that's your primary problem. You also have a scaling issue. Lose the math.sqrt when calculating scale. It's just 1/N.

Comment: So I think I am doing that - (a+j*b)(cos(wt)+j*sin(wt)) = (a*cos(wt)-b*sin(wt)) + J*(a*sin(wt) + b*cos(wt)); where w= 2 * pi * i i *jj, t = len(data_f),a = data_t[].real and b = data_t[].imag..... Here I have expanded the exponential using Eulers relationship... Can you specifically tell me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem... The plotting of the Numpy IDFT routine output is wrong, rather it should be -

```
################################################################
#Transform OFDM Data to time domain
################################################################
def IDFT(OFDM_data):
    return np.fft.ifft(absOFDM_data)

OFDM_time = IDFT(OFDM_data)
print ("Number of OFDM samples in time-domain before CP: ", len(OFDM_time))
print(OFDM_time)
plt.plot(abs(OFDM_time))  **##need to take the absolute val**
plt.show()
```

[image]